# swift function value keeps returning nil error

Tags: swift

Writing a simple swift app to practice, Its a a tarot card iphone app(press a button and a quote/image changes). Ive got the quote changing working. But the image doesnt seem to change.  This function is location in the controller. (Its not retrieving the property)

```
//Property referencing the label in the view
@IBOutlet weak var lblAnswers: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var imgCard: UIImageView!



@IBAction func askTheOracle(sender:UIButton) {

    // Retrieve a random message from the oracle
    lblAnswers?.text = model.respond()

    // Change the image in the UIImageView to the currently selected card
    imgCard?.image = UIImage(named:model.currentCardImageName)
}
```

debugger error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
imgCard is nil

See:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Where does trigger the debugger the fatal error? In askTheOracle?

Comment: it says imgCard = (UIImageView) nil

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/daq25irgzim7txj/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-22%20at%2012.35.15%20pm.png?dl=0              https://www.dropbox.com/s/e716a1da4rqt612/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-22%20at%2012.35.30%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: If `imgCard` is `nil`, then either (a) you have not hooked up the outlet correctly (check in IB); or (b) you instantiated the view controller incorrectly (you'd have to show us that code). I'd also log `model.currentCardImageName` to make sure it corresponds to an image in your project.

Comment: i put all the code up (link above) i still cant seem to pick out where the problem is exactly?

Comment: Looks like your currentCardImageName does not match to a valid image, and UIImage(named:) returns nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to ensure that UIImage(named:model.currentCardImageName) is not nil before you try to set imgCard?.image to it.

```
@IBAction func askTheOracle(sender:UIButton) {

    // Retrieve a random message from the oracle
    lblAnswers?.text = model.respond()

    // Change the image in the UIImageView to the currently selected card
    if let newImage = UIImage(named:model.currentCardImageName)
    {
          imgCard?.image = newImage
    }
}
```

If you still receive the error, ensure that imgCard is connected to your storyboard correctly.

Comment: tried adding that to both the model and controller. errors both times. What do you mean if imgCard is connected to the storyboard correctly?

Comment: You are getting which error? if you are still getting the nil error that means your imgCard is nil. Are you connecting a UIImageView from your storyboard to the IBOutlet "imgCard"? if you are, try to control-drag again and connect it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgjwpoiqlbmngz9/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-22%20at%201.33.30%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: can you make that screenshot bigger it appears your code comes after a `}` what is it coming after?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgyoiaxmag0jztu/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-22%20at%201.37.31%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: You should use that code to replace the code where it was getting an error originally. In the `askTheOracle` function. Check my update.

Comment: so no errors this time. (quote changes but the image still doesnt)

Comment: That means your program cannot find the image it is looking for. Add NSLog(model.currentCardImageName) and see if you have it in your application

Comment: thats probably it. not sure why its happening but will just ask my teacher. thanks for the help.